# When Django admin is loaded on a mobile device to hide some of the items

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

as I am loading my page using django_admin. Can somebody tell me how to disable loading some of the items for mobile? I've searched the web but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

**You can solve your problem this way:**

*views.py file*

```
def mobile_view(request):
    ...
    is_mobile = request.user_agent.is_mobile
    context = {
    .....
    'is_mobile': is_mobile
    }
   return render(request, 'app/yourHTML.html', context)
```

*yourHTML.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 ......
 {{ if is_mobile }}
     //Keep the content here to be displayed to the mobile device.
 {{ else }}
     //Content to be hidden from mobile device.
 {{ endif }}
</html>
```

**OR YOU CAN ALSO TRY THIS**

*yourHTML.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 ......
 {{ if request.user_agent.is_mobile }}
     //Keep the content here to be displayed to the mobile device.
 {{ else }}
     //Content to be hidden from mobile device.
 {{ endif }}
</html>
```